# How to pass data in restful api in angularjs

Tags: mysql, angularjs, rest

I want to add a new entry in a mysql table. I tested API from an advanced restful client. It's working fine.

but when I tried with angular js, entry is not getting added.

service code:

```
sampleApp.factory('Brand', function ($resource) {
   return $resource('http://<mydomain>/api/v1/brands/:id');
});
```

controller code:

```
$scope.brand = new Brand();
$scope.brand.id = parseInt($scope.Brands[$scope.Brands.length-1].id, 10) + 1;
$scope.brand.name = $filter('toTitleCase')($scope.NewBrand.name);  
$scope.brand.image = '/images/brands/' + $filter('toLowerCase')($scope.NewBrand.name) + '.png'; 


Brand.save($scope.brand, function() {
        alert('data saved');    
        //data saved. do something here.
});
```

what is wrong here? can anyone help on this?

Comment: Can you show us the response for your request (`$resource('http://<mydomain>/api/v1/brands/:id'`)

Comment: first place to start is browser dev tools network and inspect the actual request to see exactly what is sent...status, url etc as well as server response in body. You have to isolate server side vs client side issues

Comment: Also when tested in restful client was request sent as `application/json`? Or form encoded?

Comment: @SherlockedNguyen This is the response for rest API. {
"error": false
"message": "Brand created successfully"
"brand_id": "334"
}

Comment: @charlietfl when tested with rest client content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Rest API is fine but can you give us the request + response when you run your application in browser.

Comment: ok that is not default of `$http` . Are you using php? Either need to receive as json on server or convert to using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to send. That is most likely the issue you have

Comment: @charlietfl yes i am using php. i can not change at receiving end. Can u help me how to change at sending side?

Answer (score 0):

To convert to sending as form encoded instead of default `application/json` the following example is copied from the angular docs for [$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

```
.controller(function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  //...

  $http({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });

});
```

You can also set global defaults for all `$http` in config phase of app

Also look up in `$http` docs alternative approach to pass serializer as a string name

If you are using jQuery the serializer is the same as [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)